# How to read parameters from WorkflowPipelineArgs

Tags: pipelines, workflow

[image]

The above action is configured with parameters. How can get the parameter value in `WorkflowPipelineArgs`?

`args.parameters` returning the null value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `args.ProcessorItem.InnerItem` to find the current Sitecore Item and then from this Item, you can access any field of that item.
So, this is your process method for WorkflowAction class:

```
public void Process(WorkflowPipelineArgs args)
        {
            CreateContext(args);
        }
```

and then in this context method, you can use this args to fetch Sitecore Item:

```
private void CreateContext(WorkflowPipelineArgs args)
        {
            Item _innerItem = args.ProcessorItem?.InnerItem;
             NameValueCollection _params = WebUtil.ParseUrlParameters(_innerItem?["parameters"] ?? string.Empty);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Already found the solution. Anyway, this is the correct answer to the question.